# js get substring up to the first N digits

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a bunch of strings which are in various formats, some examples:

```
a1bbb
aa1bb
a11bbb
aa111bbb
...
```

I'm interested in getting several substrings:

A substring up to and including any digits, i.e.

```
a1
aa1
a11
aa111
```

A substring up to and including no more than 2 digits, i.e.

```
a1
aa1
a1
aa11
```

And a substring to get only chars before any digit, i.e.

```
a
aa
a
aa
```

For this i've been using

```
var prefix = str.match(/^(.+?)\d/);
```

and that seems to work. Is this a good method to use?

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For getting text before any digit you can juse use:

```
/^\D*/gm
```

Where `\D` represents any non-digit and `^` will match them at start.

Similarly no more than 2 digits regex:

```
/^\D*\d{0,2}/gm
```

And for any digit:

```
/^\D*\d*/gm
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vE9tD3/1)

Answer (score 0):

It is a possible way. However using negated character classes instead of a lazy quantifier `+?` is more performant because a lazy quantifier must test the next character for each character it grabs. A negated character class with a greedy quantifier hasn't this constraint, it takes all possible characters and tests the next subpattern only after. This is why it goes faster:

```
^([^0-9]+)[0-9]
```